# в Discord боте не вызывается метод (Python)

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Вопрос про discord.py. У меня есть класс который должен что-то сделать, но не в дискорде, он вызывает метод в другом классе `congig.get()` сам метод:

```
def get():

    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=settings['prefix'])
    client = discord.Client()

    async def on_message(message):
        if message.author == client.user:
            return

        if message.content.startswith('$id '):
            token = message.content.replace('$id ','')
            await message.channel.send(id)
            global ID
            ID = id
```

Но он почему-то не работает. Есть еще файл с командами для бота.

Comment: спасибо конечно что опечатки исправляете но почему бы не помочь просто?

Answer (score 0):

Обработчики событий в `discord-py` должны быть помечены декоратором `@bot.event`, чтобы функции вызывались при определенных событиях.

Подробнее можно почитать [**здесь**](https://github.com/denisnumb/discord-py-guide/blob/main/discord-py.md#%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9).